# What's coming in Ubuntu 18.04's 3rd point release

Tags: 18.04, kernel

So,the WiFi driver on my system has a memory leak problem, known for a while. I'm running on 18.04.2 with HWE pack ergo Linux Kernel 4.18.

Since memory leak issue is fixed in 4.20 or next version (5.0 ?), I wanted to know whether/when will it be available, because I either can wait for a while or get a USB WiFi adapter. But even though point release is scheduled on 1st August, 2019, the point release page on ubuntu.com is not set up and I've not seen any announcements as such popup in google search, so I'm not sure what's new in 18.04.3. Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: Why not install 4.20? It is pretty easy to do. UKUU made it very easy https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Comment: I can definitely try but I am skeptical as I've not used this application and would prefer to get official software.

Comment: Oh, I got a new system a couple of weeks ago and have  couple of keys that are not supported. installing kernel 5.1 was a matter of seconds with UKUU. and a matter of seconds removing it . It is absolutely brilliantly simple to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel version 5.0 is available in the official repositories, to install recent version use:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.0.0-20 linux-headers-5.0.0-20-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-20-generic linux-image-5.0.0-20-generic
```

After installing the package `linux-lowlatency-hwe-18.04` the new kernel is now updated automatically:

```
sudo apt install linux-lowlatency-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Are there issues/caveats that I should be aware of before trying this?

Comment: @lawki I have 5.0.0-16 running at the moment and it works great. The caveat is that you manually have to upgrade to newer kernels, it's not auto-updated like the standard kernel. That's why I'm still with 5.0.0-16.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to track such things is probably [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net). For 18.04 (Bionic Beaver), see [Bionic (18.04) : Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic). In the third point release, 19.04's kernel, i.e. 5.0, will be available via HWE. I'm not sure about the memory leak issue but at this point of time 3 bugs are targeted (See [ubuntu-18.04.3 : Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-18.04.3)). As the time passes, new bugs/issues would be reported and you might see increase in targeted bugs, i.e. bugs to be fixed. So, it's hard to interpret what *exactly* is coming with third point release as of now.